# Formula in VBA and be used whithin VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to actulize my exel chart, I use the following code:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = Sheets("Data").Range("K5").Value
```

I want to use the K5 value in the code ( not to keep in a cell)

so i did the following:

```
Dim MaxY As Integer

MaxY = ("=MAX(K3+50,ROUNDUP(IF(OR(ISBLANK('Station info'!C12),ISBLANK('Station info'!C8)),MAX(ABS(MIN(Data!B3:B10000)),ABS(MAX(Data!B3:B10000))),IF(('Station info'!C8-MAX(ABS(MIN(Data!B3:B10000)),ABS(MAX(Data!B3:B10000)))-MAX(Data!B3:B10000)+MIN(Data!B3:B10000))<'Station info'!C12,'Station info'!C8-'Station info'!C12+1,MAX(ABS(MIN(Data!B3:B10000)),ABS(MAX(Data!B3:B10000))))),0))") 


 ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = Sheets("Data").MaxY.Value

end sub
```

It is not working, but the formula works if I put in K5 and refer to K5.

How can I solve this problem and define the teh formula and keep it within VBA code??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this. You might need an extra bracket in your formula. `MaxY` is a variable so you want to access its value directly; it does not "belong" to a worksheet.

```
Sub x()

Dim MaxY As Integer

With Range("A1")
    .Formula = "=MAX(K3+50,ROUNDUP(IF(OR(ISBLANK('Station info'!C12),ISBLANK('Station info'!C8)),MAX(ABS(MIN(Data!B3:B10000)),ABS(MAX(Data!B3:B10000))),IF(('Station info'!C8-MAX(ABS(MIN(Data!B3:B10000)),ABS(MAX(Data!B3:B10000)))-MAX(Data!B3:B10000)+MIN(Data!B3:B10000))<'Station info'!C12,'Station info'!C8-'Station info'!C12+1,MAX(ABS(MIN(Data!B3:B10000)),ABS(MAX(Data!B3:B10000))))),0))"
    MaxY = .Value
    .Clear
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Have you checked your formula is valid? Try entering it in a cell.

Comment: it work in a cell but not within the code , i read that the reason is because we use excel function (max in this case) and VBA has similar function

Comment: I have no idea why that happens. I've posted a workaround above which works. Put the formula in a cell (any unused cell anywhere), use the value of that cell, and then remove the formula.